# Android - need a true trick or hat to lock/unloack the home button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I have read a lot about it, and many people stating that it's a bad design ... and so on.. but there are some apps that must benefit of locking / unmocking the home button to prevent unintentionally click/ press on the GUI during an activity processing...

I have such app, in which a specific activit is currently running full-screen ( so no up/back button active) and the STOP button of the activity can be pressed ONLY when a slider has been moved to enable the STOP button... this running fine...and the device can be moved up/done , or whatever action ... if the slider is not wiped .. no way to stop it...

BUT, the home button can still be pressed unintentionally ( so is the other system button on the right.. to reduce the window...)

Is there anyway to lock them ( and unock them) programmatically ???  ant trick.. any hack...this is a pure prototype using smartphone, the final project will run inside a blackbox ...

thanks for your suggestions....  androidly yours

Comment: I would immediately uninstall your App if you did this.  People keep telling you it's bad design, but they mean HORRIBLE.

Comment: I am really pleased to say that Android does not allow apps to take control of my home button.  **I** will control how my device works, not you.

Comment: you'll NEVER get my app , it's a pure company internal app... it'll be never on sale or distributed  outside ... I actually explain it in my question and I wa snot waiting for your personal feeling, but for a technical answer, sorry if you misunderstood it

Comment: If it's supposed to be a panel app. I wouldn't be worried to much about it. Just make sure nobody can touch the buttons. If the final project will run inside a blackbox... just don't add those buttons in a way they can be touched. Sounds like you're trying to build some kind of ATM or Terminal app. Better spend time on something that will be needed by the final product.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop the home button functioning, with any trick

Think about malicious people - it would allow them to create an app for instance, that would not let you leave until you paid a fee

Comment: I understand in the case of a smartphone app...  in our case , we use the smartphone as a pilot project box for running Android operating system...

Comment: You're right, you should contact Google and ask them to make an exception for you guys! Maybe they can create a whole branch of the OS for you

Comment: I don't understand the tone of your answer... ( see Loic's one above..)   not all people have the same needs using an open OS..  you should open your mind and try to understand why people ask question... and answer accordingly